# How to write and solve first order differential equation to second order system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

This is my first post. I've got a problem about how to approach this exercise because I don't understand how it can be converted to non-homogenous second order system.

The initial problem is

$$y'(t)=\frac{1}{2}y(t)+2$$

with initial condition $y(0)=1$.

Then is converted to this system:

$$x_{1}'(t)=\frac{-1}{2}x_{1}(t)+2x_{2}(t)$$
$$x_{2}'(t)=0$$

with initial conditions $$x_{1}(0)=x_{2}(0)=1$$

I tried to understand how to convert it to that kind of system. So, I tried to find a matrix $A$ and calculate $e^{At}$ for determinating $x_{1}(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ at any instant of time.

This is just mathematical curiosity and I would like any help to find a correct procedure. So this is my procedure (the text is in Spanish, but procedure is main topic).

[My procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbErL.jpg)

I guess it's a total mess, but I would like to understand more about this topic.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you sure the first ODE in the system is $x_{1}' = -x_{1}/2 + \dots$ and not $x_{1}' = x_{1}/2 + \dots$?

Comment: Hi, well, I am not assuming, the exercise was written like that, I just tried to understand, so I am not sure if that is the correct system, that is the reason why I require help and receiving ideas, any help is welcome.

Comment: Converting this ODE into a 2x2 linear system and applying matrix methods to solve it, is a rather bizarre idea. If your TA cannot think of more convincing examples of the method, then *you have a problem (Houston)*... If, on the other hand, this is your own idea, then you should try instead the change of variable $$z(t)=y(t)+4$$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Mattos is right and you made a typo, then what do you know about $x_2'(t)=0$? The variable must be a constant. Furthermore, you know $x_2(0)=1$, so it starts from $1$ and remains constant, thus it is $1$! Then it is easy to see that $x_1$ resembles the homogeneous part of $y$ and you have your system $x'=Ax$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1'\\
x_2'
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 2\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
Now to compute $x(t)$ find the matrix exponential(by diagonalization).

**Edit:**
In short, we have distinct eigenvalues $\lambda=\{1/2,0\}$ then we can write $AT=T\Lambda$ for $\Lambda = \mathrm{diag}(1/2,0)$ and $T = [v_{1/2} \;\; v_0]$; the corresponding eigenvectors. Then we seek $e^{At} = \sum^{\infty}_{k=0} \frac{(At)^n}{n!}$, which might look hard, but if you plug in $A=T\Lambda T^{-1}$ from before, it follows that:
\begin{align}
e^{At} = Te^{\Lambda t}T^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -4\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{\frac{1}{2} t} & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
e^{\frac{1}{2} t} & 4e^{\frac{1}{2} t} -4\\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
such that 
\begin{equation}
x(t) = e^{A t} x_0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Hi, that is an interesting procedure, I guess matrix T depends of eigenvalues and T^-1 is its inverse, so, I have a question: where did that e^(1/2t) come from?. About the conversion of the system, if it's well converted of there is a mistake in the conversion, but thanks for your help.

Comment: (made a small edit) The $e^{\frac{1}{2} t}$ follows from the fact that the matrix exponential of a diagonal matrix can be found by taking the exponents of its components individually. So $(\frac{1}{2} t) \mapsto e^{\frac{1}{2}t}$. This procedure is very general and used all the time in linear differential equations/systems theory. Especially the so-called Jordan form, which generalizes this approach to systems where the eigenvectors do not span the entire solution space.

Comment: Ahhh well, that's a good explanation, thanks very much, it helped me to understand it, but I don't know still if the conversion of the system is correct, even the exercise says it's like that way, but the explanation of the exponential matrix is awesome, thanks again.